# Order data for ggplot2 geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use create a heatmap of the following data in a heatmap:

```
IND1    IND2    FREQ
Alix    Bob     3
Bob     Crit    5
Alix    Alix    7
Fang    Fang    2
Alix    Crit    1
Crit    Dix     9
Dix     Alix    2
Bob     Fang    3
Bob     Bob     1
```

I would also like to order the rows and columns according to the type of Individual. So, I have added 2 columns to the data to make it look as follows:

```
IND1    IND2    FREQ    IND1.TYPE   IND2.TYPE
Alix    Bob     3       Dog         Cat
Bob     Crit    5       Cat         Dog
Alix    Alix    7       Dog         Dog
Fang    Fang    2       Dog         Dog
Alix    Crit    1       Dog         Dog
Crit    Dix     9       Dog         Cat
Dix     Alix    2       Cat         Dog
Bob     Fang    3       Cat         Dog
Bob     Bob     1       Cat         Cat
```

Essentially, I want the dogs to be grouped together and the Cats to be grouped together also along the X and Y axis. I am using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713713/order-data-inside-a-geom-tile) to do the ordering:

```
tr$IND1<-factor(tr$IND1, levels=(tr$IND1)[order(tr$IND1.TYPE)])
tr$IND2<-factor(tr$IND2, levels=(tr$IND2)[order(tr$IND2.TYPE)])
```

The code for the heatmap is as follows:

```
ggplot(tr, aes(IND1, IND2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = FREQ), colour = "white") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")
```

Which is producing the following plot:
[image]

Though the Dogs and Cats are getting ordered in their respective groups, I would also want them to be alphabetically ordered inside their respective groups. So, I want the rows and columns to look like:

```
Fang
Crit
Alix
Dix
Bob
   Bob  Dix  Alix  Crit Fang
```

I was of the opinion that 'order' by default sorts alphabetically inside each group based on the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631775/ordering-rows-and-columns-of-r-matrix-by-criteria) . But, this does not seem to work in this case.

So, I was wondering about the most efficient way to do the ordering to get the desired output.

Comment: Sounds like you want to order by, e.g., `IND1.TYPE` and `IND1`, not just `IND1.TYPE`.  Like `levels = unique(tr$IND1[order(tr$IND1.TYPE, tr$IND1)])`

Comment: @aosmith : Can you add that as an answer? it worked for me. So I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep your factors ordered alphabetically within the Dog/Cat groups you will need to order the levels based on both the variables.

```
tr$IND1 <- factor(tr$IND1, levels = unique(tr$IND1[order(tr$IND1.TYPE, tr$IND1)]))
tr$IND2 <- factor(tr$IND2, levels = unique(tr$IND2[order(tr$IND2.TYPE, tr$IND2)]))
```

Then your plot axes will have the desired order.

[image]